# Relationship between response and predictor in multiple linear regression model

Tags: multiple-regression, model-selection

After using model selection methods, I've arrived at a final model which removed two of the predictors out of ten. My question of interest is whether one predictor has a positive relationship with the response. The final model has a positive coefficient for that predictor, so can I say that my hypothesis was correct?

Comment: The question is vague .  present the models output along with major details  for reseaarch and hypothesis. It is difficult yo answer a question ln the present forrm